# Missing plugin library OSGEO ogr_OCI.dll

Tags: c#, ogr, osgeo

I am working on a project that uses OSGEO. I am trying to make shapefiles using OSGeo.Ogr. The first step involves registering all drivers. I am doing that (as shown in the image below). However, I get the exception as shown in the diagram, even though I have the file ogr_OCI.dll in the specified directory. I dont know if theres something wrong I am doing.

I am using VISUAL STUDIO 2017 and C# programming language.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this plugin is used for oracle. Please move the plugin to a different directory and all would be fine. Once you have oracle client installed then can bring it back it will work like charm.